# Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal NetBeans IDE 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, javac

Estaba trabajando sobre un proyecto de repente dejo de correr los proyectos. Los demás proyectos son viejos y estaban funcionando también. Pero ya ninguno corre.

[image: Imagen de la clase principal del proyecto borrar]

[image: properties/Sources]

[image: properties/Run]

Comment: Qué bueno que hayas encontrado respuesta. Por otra parte, no olvides que tanto los mensajes de error como código que llegues a subir deben ir _como texto, con formato_, ya que [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

El error se generaba por el nombre de la carpeta raíz.
Al dar clic derecho sobre el proyecto y seleccionar "Clean and Build", me mostraba el error "javac: file not found".
Esto era debido al carácter "ñ" en el nombre de la carpeta. Encontré dos soluciones.

[image: Error generado al realizar el "Clean and Build"]

Solucion 1- La solución mas sencilla es cambiar el nombre a esa carpeta.

Solucion 2- Abrir "Panel de Control", luego "Reloj y region", luego "Region". Se abre una ventana escoger la pestaña "Administrativo", seleccionar "Cambiar configuracion regional del sistema..."

Se abre una nueva ventana, se debe desmarcar la opcion, "Version beta:Use UTF-8 Unicode para la compatibilidad de idioma en todo el mundo"
[image: Proceso desmarcado de casilla]

Después de esto te pedirá reiniciar para confirmar cambios.